# read() only prints the first part of a file

Tags: python

I have a 17MB file that I am trying to parse through, but the code is only returning the first few lines before abruptly ending. It pauses in the middle of normal text (there are no special characters to cause the file to stop), so I'm not sure what's going on.

I tried googling and searching on stack overflow but the other solutions that I found online haven't really worked.

```py
f = open("foo.txt", 'r') # I also tried 'rb' instead of 'r'
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

Instead of outputting the entire foo.txt file, it only prints about 9000 characters.

Comment: If you assign `f.read()` to a variable, what's its length? Because the script you show could go wrong either at the input side (`read()`) or on the output side (`print()`), and your description doesn't give any hints to where it's going wrong. Are you sure your file contains what you expect it to?

Comment: @Blckknght: Agreed. I've never seen a plain `read()` fail to read a local disk file completely unless the file was corrupted (possibly due to a failing drive). And `print` is basically foolproof, especially since they say it fails in binary mode too (so it's not some unprintable character screwing up the terminal somehow).

Comment: @lurker Python strings are not null-terminated.

Comment: @Blckknght len(x) prints out "5570102". I can open the file and see all its contents. Yet printing it Python still on outputs less than 9000 characters.

Comment: Is it truly all printable text and newlines? There are no terminal escape codes in there that might clear the screen, etc?

Comment: @QuestionerZed: Then I suggest looking at the last characters that print out, and search for them in the big string. See if there are any unexpected characters in it just where the printing cuts off.

Comment: @Blckknght At the point where it cuts off, it's just a normal sentence. It cuts off in the middle of a word actually, but there 's no weirdness going on there I imagine.

Comment: @lurker Errr.... the text does actually have a lot of backslashes (including "\n") and sometimes uses "{{" or "}}". Not sure about terminal escape codes.

Comment: The "{{" and "}}" don't mean anything in this context. They're just ASCII, printable characters that have no special meaning to the terminal. If you mean backslashes as in ASCII coded backslashes (as in distinct \ followed by a distinct character), that's not an issue either. But if you had, for example an escape (hex code `1b`) followed by a lower case `c`, that would clear the screen of anything output so far and continue from there. Are the "about 9000" characters you are seeing the first 9000, or last or something else?

Comment: If the file has a lot of "backslash characters" and some are not `\n` (new line), `\r` (carriage return), `\f` (form feed) or `\t` (tab) then getting a sensible "print" of the data just using `print` is questionable.

Comment: @lurker It’s the first 8869 characters of the text. I know for a fact that read() is not taking all the characters (despite the length apparently being longer) because later my code stops working when I know for a fact that it should be detecting text that it is not detecting. I was just using print to try and troubleshoot.

Comment: I don't like not trusting the length read without additional experiments. What if you try a write to another file? Like, `fout = open('out.txt', 'w')` after your first open, then, `fout.write(f.read())` instead of the `print`. Does that create a file of 8896 bytes?

Answer (score -4):

You should save the f.read() to a local variable, then close the document, then print the variable out. This way the document has time to render.

Comment: There should be no rendering going on.

Comment: *load. I have had expiriences where python executes the code after an open statement before it actually has all the data from the file.

Comment: The `open` statement doesn't read the data. `read` does. The `read` is  blocking, so it won't execute the next statement until the `read` completes.

Comment: I tried this solution despite @gmds saying it wouldn't work and it did indeed not work.